# Transform ImportInliner: Could not find asset css

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a Dart project that partially uses Polymer. However, when trying to do a "pub build" I get the following error:

```
Build error:
Transform ImportInliner on icautomata_gui|web/<projectname>.html threw error: Could not find asset css|asset/<projectname>.css.
null
null
[Info from Dart2JS]:
```

However, I don't have that asset defined, and it isn't imported in my html. Is this something that is constructed automatically by the Polymer transform? When that error is thrown, no project HTML page is constructed in the build directory. It seems like the error halts the build, but doesn't flag the build as failed. Is there a workaround for this? What is needed/expected for that CSS file?

Thanks,

-D

Comment: Obviously the <projectname> is substituted for the real deal....

Comment: This seems to be an issue from polymer-0.10.0-pre.9. Upgrading to polymer-0.10.0-pre.12 seemed to solve this.